# Connecting from AWS ECS to Heroku kafka - kafka metadata-client error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs

my nodejs application is deployed on AWS ECS cluster and it's listening on port 3000, post this the nodejs connects to Heroku deployed kafka via no-kafka client i am able to **connect kafka topic subscription if I deployed my nodejs app locally (on my laptop)** but when I deploy the same on AWS ECS container then I get error.

> 2017-11-28T06:11:43.619Z **ERROR no-kafka-client Metadata request
>   failed:  AggregateError of:
>       NoKafkaConnectionError [ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9096]: Kafka server has
>   closed connection

1. I did some research and found that no-kakfa (from github) has
   **Brokerredirection** Option, I tried this but not sure the format is correct and neither i found any example any where on net to correctly give host port and kafka port.
2. another research, I opened up IP via iptables to allow port 9096 on ECS
   instances. no luck
3. nmap for the port from ECS and its able to connect to kafka broker node

   > Host is up (0.00031s latency). 
   >   PORT     STATE    SERVICE 
   >   9096/tcpfiltered unknown

this means connecting to kafka is fine but return value is the issue or connection itself is an issue. How to map kakfa port return with Docker, ECS instance port ? Please help,